# Click event not detected in UserControl

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, click

I've some UserControls which are created dynamically, with parameters :

```
foreach (DataRow dr in drc)
{
    question = (from ques in bdd.QUESTION where ques.ID_QUESTION == idQuestion select ques).FirstOrDefault();
    List<Object> listParams = new List<Object>();
    listParams.Add(question);
    AdminQuestion qa = (AdminQuestion)(Controller.LoadControl(Page, "~/UserControls/AdminQuestion.ascx", listParams.ToArray()));
    pnl_question_list.Controls.Add(qa);
}
```

This is a method I found on SoF and it works great.
This method is called when I click on a button, and all my usercontrols are correctly created.
In this usercontrol, I have a button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_validation_modify_question" runat="server" Text="Modifier" 
            CssClass="clear_left_float_left myBouton myBoutonEnvoyer" 
            OnClick="btn_validation_modify_question_Click"/>
```

And my method :

```
protected void btn_validation_modify_question_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QUESTION q = (from m in bdd.QUESTION where m.ID_QUESTION == question.ID_QUESTION select m).FirstOrDefault();
    q.MESSAGE = txt_modify_question_message.InnerText;
    q.ID_THEME = new Guid(ddl_modify_question_theme.SelectedValue);
    bdd.ApplyCurrentValues<QUESTION>("QUESTION", q);
    bdd.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I click on the button, it don't apply the method, and reload the page, like if I didn't have any declared method.

Is there something I don't know? I already used this technique and everything worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add controls dynamically, you'll normally need to do it on `Init` or `PreInit` page events. Otherwise event handlers will never work.

> > So, dynamically added controls must be programmatically added to the Web page on each and every page visit. The best time to add these controls is during the initialization stage of the page life cycle, which occurs before the load view state stage. That is, we want to have the control hierarchy complete before the load view state stage arrives. For this reason, it is best to create an event handler for the Page class's Init event in your code-behind class, and add your dynamic controls there.
> >
> > **Note**   You may be able to get away with loading your controls in the
> >     Page_Load
> >     event handler and maintaining the view state properly. It all depends on whether or not you are setting any properties of the dynamically loaded controls programmatically and, if so, when you're doing it relative to the
> >     Controls.Add(dynamicControl)
> >     line. A thorough discussion of this is a bit beyond the scope of this article, but the reason it may work is because the
> >     Controls
> >     property's
> >     Add()
> >     method recursively loads the parent's view state into its children, even though the load view state stage has passed.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4) you have more information.

**EDIT**

Just to be sure we're talking about the same, here you have how your code should look like

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    foreach (DataRow dr in drc)
    {
        question = (from ques in bdd.QUESTION where ques.ID_QUESTION == idQuestion select ques).FirstOrDefault();
        List<Object> listParams = new List<Object>();
        listParams.Add(question);
        AdminQuestion qa = (AdminQuestion)(Controller.LoadControl(Page, "~/UserControls/AdminQuestion.ascx", listParams.ToArray()));
        pnl_question_list.Controls.Add(qa);

    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I did, like that `protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)` and I also tried to add my OnClick method directly here : `btn_validation_modify_question.Click +=new EventHandler(btn_validation_modify_question_Click);`. But this still don't work...

Comment: @algelos: I've added some code to be sure that we're talking about the same

Comment: Oh ok.. But this is a big problem, because my Controls are only added if I click on a button, which search question in Database and include every question in a different UserControl, so I can't call this method in Page_Init : /. Maybe could I call the method in Page_Load when it's a PostBack ?

Comment: @algelos: You'll need to add them on Page_Init. Something you could do is adding necessary information to Session object on click handler to rebuild controls on next postback. On Pre_Init you'll check if you have to recrearte controls checking if Session contains data related to questions or not.

Comment: I finnally did it. I call my function (which create my userControls) on Page_Load when postBack is true. And after that, my usercontrols are created when page is reloaded, and the method is called :). Thanks for your informations ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  PageLoad(){
 If(!Page.IsPostBack())    
    foreach (DataRow dr in drc)
        {
            question = (from ques in bdd.QUESTION where ques.ID_QUESTION == idQuestion select ques).FirstOrDefault();
            List<Object> listParams = new List<Object>();
            listParams.Add(question);
            AdminQuestion qa = (AdminQuestion)(Controller.LoadControl(Page, "~/UserControls/AdminQuestion.ascx", listParams.ToArray()));
            pnl_question_list.Controls.Add(qa);
        }
}
```

Did you try with this solution? And not use Page_Init()?